# Cannot produce two files from same input with make

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have some input files `sheet[n].in`. For each input file, I want to produce two output files, `sheet[n].out` and `solved[n].out`. I have written this Makefile:

```
SOURCES = sheet1.in
OUT = $(SOURCES:.in=.out)
SOLVED = $(patsubst sheet%,solved%,$(OUT))

sheets: ${OUT}
solvedsheets: ${SOLVED} 
all: sheets solvedsheets

sheet%.out: sheet%.in
    cat $< > $@

solved%.out: sheet%.in
    cat <% > $@
    echo "solved!" >> $@

debug:
    @echo "OUT = ${OUT}"
    @echo "SOLVED = ${SOLVED}"
```

I test it with some dummy `sheet1.in` file containing some text. When running `make`, it does produce `sheet1.out`, but not `solved1.out`. `make debug` yields:

```
OUT = sheet1.out
SOLVED = solved1.out
```

I can remove the rule for `solved%.out` and make does not even complain about a missing rule. It seems to just ignore the `SOLVED` list as necessary output files. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `make` with no rule, Make is gonna run the first *non-pattern* rule found in the file. Thus only your `sheets` rule is called.

You have two easy solutions then:

1. Make the `all` rule the first rule in your Makefile;
2. Call `make all` instead of just `make`.

---

Simplified and more robust Makefile:

```make
SOURCE := $(wildcard *.in)
OUTPUT := $(SOURCE:.in=.out) $(SOURCE:sheet%.in=solved%.out)

.PHONY: all

all: $(OUTPUT)

sheet%.out: sheet%.in
    cat $< > $@

solved%.out: sheet%.in
    cat <% > $@
    echo "solved!" >> $@
```

Comment: Oh wow. I used it all these years simply assuming it will call `all` if given no argument.